# ssl issue with name based virtual hosting for multiple domain

Tags: apache, webserver

I have three domains:- 
**abc.local** without ssl configuration

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.0.87:80>
        ServerName abc.local
        DocumentRoot /var/www/alpha/abc.local/
        ServerAlias  hey.abc.local 
        DirectoryIndex  index.php  index.html 
        <Directory />
           Options FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/alpha/abc.local/>
           Options FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride all
           Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/abc.local/error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/abc.local/access.log combined
        <Directory /var/www/alpha/abc.local >
           AuthType Basic
           AuthName abc_test
           AuthBasicProvider file
           AuthUserFile /var/www/alpha/abc.local/.htpasswd
           Require valid-user
        </Directory>
     </VirtualHost>
```

**test.local** with ssl configuration

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.0.87:80>
        ServerName test.local
        DocumentRoot /var/www/alpha/test.local/
        ServerAlias  hey.test.local 
        DirectoryIndex  index.php  index.html 
        <Directory />
           Options FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/alpha/test.local/>
           Options FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride all
           Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/test.local/error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/test.local/access.log combined
     </VirtualHost>
   <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
     <VirtualHost 10.0.0.87:443>
        ServerName test.local
        DocumentRoot /var/www/alpha/test.local/
        ServerAlias  hey.test.local 
        DirectoryIndex  index.php  index.html 
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /var/www/alpha/ssl/test.local/test.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/alpha/ssl/test.local/test.key

        <Directory />
           Options FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/alpha/test.local/>
           Options FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride all
           Require all granted
       </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/test.local/error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/test.local/access.log combined
            SSLHonorCipherOrder On
            SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5
            SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3

      </VirtualHost>
    </ifModule>
```

and third one **example.local** have ssl configuration same like **test.local**

But issue is when i am trying to access https://abc.local it serving the content of first loaded domain from **test.local** or **example.local**